# GTK3: GtkIconView: Is it possible to style the selected cell, which have the cursor focus, differently than other selected cells?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

In an IconView, if we select some cells and hover over any of them, the cell with mouse pointer on it shows a different style, if set in css for example.

Is this same behavior possible when moving the cursor around by keyboard and hitting a selected cell. Or asked differently: is it possible to style the cell with cursor focus different than selected cells without cursor focus?

I am only interessed in GTK3 solutions for version between 3.18 and 3.24.

For GTK4 versions we "just" have to change the name of a cell, which is a widget now. So, quiet easy, or? ;)

Thanks for any guiding into the right direction.